# How can I display SAP SOAP webservices Response in Android ? using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2, sap-basis

When I run this application  I got the exception:

> 02-04 09:31:37.213: WARN/System.err(538): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
>
> (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:686 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4052d188)

How can i resolve it ? here i am using Ksoap2.jar for calling webservices  is there any alternative to call sap soap webservices with android ?
thanks in Advance...

```
package com.appu.pack;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SampleFinalSapActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private final String NAMESPACE ="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";//this is my server namespace..
    private final String METHOD_NAME ="ZMATERIALS_GROUP_LIST";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME;
    private final String URL ="http://************:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE197AD09B4D05C4345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=800&sap-user=*****&sap-password=******";
            @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        
        Request.addProperty("Language", "d"); //this is the one of the property in wsdl file 
        
        System.out.println("the  Request is :::::"+Request);
         
       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
       
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        
        System.out.println("TRANSPORT:"+androidHttpTransport);
 
 try
        {   
     
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)
         
        //Object result = envelope.getResponse(); //getting response here
                
        //SoapPrimitive result1 = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.bodyIn;
        
       // System.out.println("Result : " + result1.toString());

     SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
     
     System.out.println("RESPONSE:"+response);
        }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be a little mistake in code.I couldn't understand find that mistake.I think there may be problem in the URL.
may be you can refer my answer.
[Android Java connect to online database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493822/android-java-connect-to-online-database/9495264#9495264) 
working code is posted there.

Comment: thanks for ur Reply Here I am using the WSDL address as URL can i write like this ?