# Android database from website

Tags: java, android

i was wondering a few things.

I Have a database with 3 rows, and i have to use the database on my website cause it has to be shared with every one that downloads my app cause they can add more things.

Table is called

Poka

And the rows are
 - ID
 - word(TEXT)
 - reply(TEXT)

The Reply is hooked onto the word.

Sense there can be more then 1 of the same "word" text i need it to search threw each of the word that was inputed in the EditText and pick a random reply from that and display it in EditText . And if there are no words, it will say cannot find one.

Comment: How can i do what i said above?

Comment: That depends, what database are you using, which web application framework?

Comment: Mysql 5.0, hosted on 1and1.com

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to use text box edit listener whenever the value of text box changes call the web service that give you response depend on what you send to it and then pass that response to text box.
refer the[refer the answer of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493822/android-java-connect-to-online-database/9495264#9495264)

in above link I explain the answer with code.Using that that code you can definitely do that.
the main thing is built web service so that it give you proper response.Just return table of words from the web service then catch that table get relevant column data and show it in your application.

```
 obj3.getProperty(0).toString();//id
obj3.getProperty(1).toString();//word
```

If you returning id and word nad you want only word column then you can choose

```
 obj3.getProperty(1).toString();//word
```

all the answer is explain in above link.refer that too.
Please write comment if you are facing more problem in that.

Comment: I get a error under the text "prm_value" which says prm_value cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: request.addProperty("parm_name",prm_value);// Parameter for Method

Comment: make sure the parm_name is same as parameter_name in web service and prm_value type must match with type in web service **ex:suppose emp_sal type in web service is "String" and in our program it is Double ,so we need to cast it to String request.addProperty("emp_sal",String.valueOf(34444));**