# Connect to an online SQL database in Android

Tags: android, database, sql-server-2005

I am developing my android app which interacts with an external MSSQL database (SQL server 2005). But dont have any clue on how to make that possible...so I referred some articles like..

[Android Java connect to online database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493822/android-java-connect-to-online-database)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/9KCkhHP2_RY

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/YCRt2HducKg

but couldn't get it through. can anyone plz explain me how can i make it possible with some basic tutorials or code.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one server side application to interact and get data from database

Then run that server side app and using any web service protocol connect to this server     side app by android client app.

Check this link

Here they using hessian web service protocol

http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/06/simple-messaging-example-using-hessian/

Comment: @vishwa-So I should first built a program to interact with database outside Android framework...??

Comment: yes.it will be a server side app and its should be running on server

Comment: from android app you cannot directly connect to external database

Comment: @vishwa- I read something on Internet about REST. Do you have any idea about that..and thanks for reply

Comment: REST is also one web service, to implement REST both service and client should be in REST

Comment: Thank you very much...I will try to implement it. But will ask if i go in any trouble. And +1 or good explanation,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14164/discussion-between-nilayonandroid-and-vishwa)

Comment: ok fine, i have knowledge about hessian web service if you got any trouble in that i will try to help you